# Why can't I compile jsp?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat10, java-19

I have such an assembly Eclipse EE + Java 19 + Tomcat 10. When starting a simple JSP, this error comes out:

> -ERROR505  java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available for configuration options compilerClassName: [null] and compiler:
> [null].

What could be the problem?

[image: console]

what has already been done is reinstalling tomcat10

Comment: This might be caused by a number of things. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In addition: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].